# Is it possible to perform broadcasting in SQL as part of an insert statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, sql-insert

Imagine I have a table `table1` which contains multiple rows of data.

```
table1:
=======

id: | value:
------------
  1 |     10
  2 |     20
  3 |     30
```

and another table, which I have just created, containing two columns:

```
table2:
=======

id: | value1: | value2:
-----------------------
```

Is it possible to iterate over the rows in `table1`, using those values to insert into `table2`?

This is essentially a copying operation with insertion of some additional fixed data.

Here's what I tried:

```
insert into table2 (value1, value2)
values
    (
        (select value from table1),
        100
    );
```

which does not work, for the anticipated reason:

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

A possible solution might be to create the table gradually, by adding columns 1 at a time. However, assuming this isn't possible, can it be done another way?

I thought it might be possible to "expand" `table1` to have the required number of columns by doing something like an inner join. But I don't think this is quite the right approach either...

```
insert into table2 (value1, value2)
values (select value1, value2 from table1 inner join 100) -- not quite right, want value2 to be set to 100
```

The idea would be to do something analogous to Python/Pandas "broadcasting".

Perhaps it can be done using a temporary table?

The easy non-SQL way would obviously be to write a Python script...

Comment: SQL DML in practically every RDBMS is always strictly restricted to mutating a single table at a time - it's a _good thing_ because otherwise it'd be impossible to have sane locking, concurrency, and transactions.

Comment: ...that said, in Postgres there's the `RETURNING` clause, and T-SQL (MSSQL) has `OUTPUT INTO` which can be used in one DML statement to `INSERT` _deltas_ into a second table - but this isn't the same thing that you're thinking of.

Comment: `table2` has three columns `id, value1, value2`. Do you want the `id` column to match that of `table1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an insert-select statement, where the `100` is a literal in the select list:

```sql
INSERT INTO table2 (value1, value2)
SELECT value, 100
FROM   table1
```

Comment: Can this be extended to select values from more than one table?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yes, you can use a `JOIN` or `UNION` operator in the `SELECT` query that feeds the `INSERT INTO` statement.